# Reload Database Objects without reloading entire Page

Tags: django, database, sqlite

I have a django project with two main templates.
One will post stuff to a database and the other one will display the stuff in the database.
Is there any way that the display template could reload the database objects without reloading the entire page?

Comment: django doesn't work like that. If you want to reload and refresh specfic bits you will need to use javascript and APIs. I'd look at something like react or vue.js together with django-rest-framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course. You can simply use AJAX requests (frontend) to do so. On backend you have to define endpoints that will render the response as a JSON formatted data. There are a couple of solutions to achieve it, but the most popular are:
- Django REST Framework
- JsonResponse

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
return JsonResponse({'foo':'bar'})
```

Comment: okay thanks , that looks like a reasonable approach. but what keeps me from reading the JSON formated data  processing it a little with python and then displaying it with a standard {% idk $} Django tag. That would skip the whole ajax part